# RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled distribution group parameters

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, exchange-server

I create distribution group using PowerShell in a C# app.
I want ot change the parameter which allow external users to send mail to this group.

On the the technet I found https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa998856(v=exchg.160).aspx
And I try to add a parameter to my PowerShell command. For executing PowerShell in my app I use the way :

```
ps.Commands = new PSCommand().AddCommand("New-DistributionGroup").AddParameter("Name", "GRP_DIF_" + textBox1.Text);
ps.Invoke();
```

This code create a distribution group successfully but when I want to change the parameter

> RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled

using

```
[...].AddParameter("RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled", "$false")
```

I have an

> Unknow parameter : RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled

Is there a special way to change this parameter ?

Comment: Are you targeting Exchange 2013? `New-DistributionGroup` doesn't have that parameter, you'll need to set it using `Set-DistributionGroup` subsequently

Comment: Working well thank you